# iOS 8 Extension

Tags: ios8, ios8-extension

In iOS 8 is it possible to invoke extension menu from a button on website (i.e. using javascript) in safari ?

I am able to invoke the extension menu from a password field in one of my iOS APP. Like in image below.
http://blog.agilebits.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Instapaper-1Password-extension.png

I want to do the same when i open my website in safari. So when user selects 1Password button from website page it should open this menu or share menu with 1Password extension. Not that user go and select share menu then 1Password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in Safari currently. What you are seeing in the Instapaper application is only possible using iOS SDK.

If you write a thin app around your website, this is also possible. You can signal from Javascript to your app that you want the activity used, and when the user finished, signal your website the information with Javascript.